# Couldn't read row 0, column 3 from a CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, try-catch, registro

Estoy haciendo una app de Registro y me aparece usando try catch me aparece este error en la aplicacion al ingresar "123" en Id/Usuario y "admin" en Contraseña

**Couldn't  read row 0, col 3 from a CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it**

esta es mi base de datos:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos) {
        BaseDeDatos.execSQL("create table usuarios(idsenati int primary key, nombre text, apellido text, contraseña text, carrera text)");
        BaseDeDatos.execSQL("insert into usuarios(idsenati,contraseña) values('123','admin')"); //Para probar si funciona el registro
    }

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatos, int i, int i1) {

    }
```

El error sale al ingresar los datos de Usuario y contraseña del MainActivity

```
public void Ingresar(View view) {
        BaseDeDatosApp admin = new BaseDeDatosApp(this, "usuarios", null, 1);
        SQLiteDatabase BaseDeDatosApp = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        String usuario = et_usuario.getText().toString();
        String password = et_password.getText().toString();


        if (!usuario.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            @SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor Validar = BaseDeDatosApp.rawQuery("select idsenati from usuarios where idsenati='" +
                    usuario + "' and contraseña='" + password + "'", null);

            try {
                if (Validar.moveToFirst()) {
                    String user = Validar.getString(0);
                    String pass = Validar.getString(3);
                    //preguntamos si los datos ingresados son iguales
                    if (usuario.equals(user) && password.equals(pass)) {
                        //si son iguales entonces vamos a otra ventana
                        //Menu es una nueva actividad empty
                        Intent ven = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
                        //lanzamos la actividad
                        startActivity(ven);
                        //limpiamos las las cajas de texto
                        et_usuario.setText("");
                        et_password.setText("");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
//En esta parte me avisa del error al iniciar Ingresar en la app
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Ocurrio un Error " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Debe introducir el Id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            BaseDeDatosApp.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisas tu consulta, esta indica obtener solo el campo `idsenati`:

```
"select idsenati from usuarios where ....
```

pero tu estás tratando de leer un campo en la posición 4 (`Validar.getString(3)`) el cual obviamente no existe en el cursor.

```
String pass = Validar.getString(3);
```

modifica tu consulta para que obtenga los campos necesarios, probablemente necesites realizar toda la consulta:

```
 "select * from usuarios where ....
```